# How to set the different MenuItem background in a navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and i add programmatically some items like this:

```
navigationView = (NavigationView)ControllerParams.activity.findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
drawerMenu = navigationView.getMenu();

MenuItem menuItem1 = drawerMenu.add("1");
MenuItem menuItem2 = drawerMenu.add("2");
MenuItem menuItem3 = drawerMenu.add("3");
MenuItem menuItem3 = drawerMenu.add("4");
```

How can I change the background color of the third element programmatically?

Thanks

Comment: so you looking for change menuItem3 background color ?

Comment: exact, i want to change it programmatically!